# How do I target a SPECIFIC template with is_page_template() in Wordpress 3+

Tags: wordpress

I'm running Wordpress 3.2 and I need a conditional to test for a **certain** template. My template is a file called special_offer.php. The name of the template is "Special Offer". I've tried both of the following:

```
is_page_template('special_offer.php');
is_page_template('Special Offer');
```

Neither of these work! The [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) clearly says that the parameter should be a string with the name of the *file* so I'm not sure what's wrong. I know the function is at least partially working because if I don't include a parameter, it returns true for any pages using templates (as expected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHA!
I solved this by adding `wp_reset_query()` just before the conditional.

I had already read warnings about many WP conditionals not working inside the loop. However, my conditional is NOT inside a loop. **Turns out, it won't work even AFTER the loop, which is where mine was.** So you you need to reset the query before you call it.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth double checking which file is being used according to the [WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) [image].

Try adding this magic constant to the template file you think is being called:

```
<?php echo(__FILE__); ?>
```

If you don't see a path and filename a different file is being used (refer to the template hierarchy diagram in the link above) or check which templates are available:

```
<?php print_r( get_page_templates() ); ?>
```

(^ looks like this has to be called from the admin interface e.g. in a plugin)

Also, the documentation seems to state that is_page_template() won't work in the Loop without calling another function first.

Comment: I was definitely editing the correct template file in this case, but that's a good tip especially for anyone who isn't very familiar with the template hierarchy. The magic __FILE__ constant is also cool to know about.